# Windows 8.1 - How to activate multiple machines

Tags: windows-8, automation, windows-activation

So, I work for a company that recently purchased around 50 HP slim line desktops (System model: HP EliteDesk 800 G1 USDT).  Each machine has Windows 8 already installed.  The machines were never used previously, and when you turn each of them on you have to go through the windows 8 setup and give the machine a name, create an account, etc.  After I set one of them up, I am asked to activate my copy of windows by calling a 1888 number and talking to a interactive prompt, reading the install ID, etc.

Basically, this has really started to be a bottleneck in regard to getting these machines out the door to clients.   I have checked the product keys, and every single machine has had the same exact product key - but I still have to call the 1888 number in order to activate each windows install.  The activation works just fine every time, but if you have ever had to call Microsoft to activate windows, just imagine doing that 50 times in a short period of time..

Now, I am not asking for help with software piracy (seeing as how we have valid licenses for each machine), I just want to know if there is any way I can copy the activation from one machine to the next seeing as how each machine has the same product key?   Is this possible?   And if so, how do I do this?    I can't imagine a large enterprise that has thousands of machines to deploy having to call Microsoft to activate each one.

Comment: The computers shouldn't have the same product key.  Sounds like something is off, because by that fact alone, points to the fact you don't actually have a valid license for each machine.  Now in most cases of a volume license, yes they would be the same, but you also would create a single deployaable image after it was already activated.

Comment: In such big enviroments you may have some kind of software/os deployment. If you use deployment methods or volume keys you also may have an Key Management Server (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff793434.aspx). Its strange in any way because when we get oem desktops we also have to do the setup but i never had to activate them. Do you have an internet connection there?